# MATLAB: Subtracting matrix subsets by specific rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Here is an example of a subset of the matrix I would like to use:

> 1 3 5
>
> 2 3 6
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 3 5 4
>
> 5 5 5
>
> 8 8 0

This matrix is in fact 3000 x 3.

For the first 3 rows, I wish to subtract each of these rows with the first row of these three.

For the second 3 rows, I wish to subtract each of these rows with the first of these three, and so on.

As such, the output matrix will look like:

> 0 0 0
>
> 1 0 1
>
> 0 -2 -4
>
> 0 0 0
>
> 2 0 1
>
> 5 3 -4

What code in MATLAB will do this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a slightly shorter and vectorized way will be (if `a` is your matrix) :

```
b=a-kron(a(1:3:end,:),ones(3,1));
```

let's test:

```
a=[1 3 5
   2 3 6
   1 1 1
   3 5 4
   5 5 5
   8 8 0]

a-kron(a(1:3:end,:),ones(3,1))

ans =
 0     0     0
 1     0     1
 0    -2    -4
 0     0     0
 2     0     1
 5     3    -4
```

### Edit

Here's a bsxfun solution (less elegant, but hopefully faster):

```
a-reshape(bsxfun(@times,ones(1,3),permute(a(1:3:end,:),[2 3 1])),3,[])'

ans =

 0     0     0
 1     0     1
 0    -2    -4
 0     0     0
 2     0     1
 5     3    -4
```

### Edit 2

Ok, this got me curios, as I know bsxfun starts to be less efficient for bigger array sizes. So I tried to check using `timeit` my two solutions (because they are one liners it's easy). And here it is:

```
range=3*round(logspace(1,6,200));
for n=1:numel(range)
    a=rand(range(n),3);
    f=@()a-kron(a(1:3:end,:),ones(3,1));
    g=@() a-reshape(bsxfun(@times,ones(1,3),permute(a(1:3:end,:),[2 3 1])),3,[])';
    t1(n)=timeit(f);
    t2(n)=timeit(g);
end
semilogx(range,t1./t2);
```

[image]

So I didn't test for the for loop and Divkar's bsxfun, but you can see that for arrays smaller than 3e4 kron is better than bsxfun, and this changes at larger arrays (ratio of <1 means kron took less time given the size of the array). This was done at Matlab 2012a win7 (i5 machine)

Comment: D'oh! I keep forgetting about `kron`! Nice :)

Comment: no worries... :) I bet Luis Mendo will come up with a bsxfun solution in the next 10 minutes... :)

Comment: This isn't fair... I was sleeping! @rayryeng natan :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry! I had to steal the moment ;)

Answer (score 12):

You could also do this completely vectorized by using `mat2cell`, `cellfun`, then `cell2mat`.  Assuming our matrix is stored in `A`, try:

```
numBlocks = size(A,1) / 3;
B = mat2cell(A, 3*ones(1,numBlocks), 3);
C = cellfun(@(x) x - x([1 1 1], :), B, 'UniformOutput', false);
D = cell2mat(C); %//Output
```

The first line figures out how many 3 x 3 blocks we need.  This is assuming that the number of rows is a multiple of 3.  The second line uses `mat2cell` to decompose each 3 x 3 block and places them into individual cells.  The third line then uses `cellfun` so that for each cell in our cell array (which is a 3 x 3 matrix), it takes each row of the 3 x 3 matrix and subtracts itself with the first row.  This is very much like what @David did, except I didn't use `repmat` to minimize overhead.  The fourth line then takes each of these matrices and stacks them back so that we get our final matrix in the end.

Example (this is using the matrix that was defined in your post):

```
A = [1 3 5; 2 3 6; 1 1 1; 3 5 4; 5 5 5; 8 8 0];
numBlocks = size(A,1) / 3;
B = mat2cell(A, 3*ones(1, numBlocks), 3);
C = cellfun(@(x) x - x([1 1 1], :), B, 'UniformOutput', false);
D = cell2mat(C);
```

Output:

```
D =

 0     0     0
 1     0     1
 0    -2    -4
 0     0     0
 2     0     1
 5     3    -4
```

In hindsight, I think @David is right with respect to performance gains.  Unless this code is repeated many times, I think the `for` loop will be more efficient.  Either way, I wanted to provide another alternative.  Cool exercise!

### Edit: Timing and Size Tests

Because of our discussion earlier, I have decided to do timing and size tests.  These tests were performed on an Intel i7-4770 @ 3.40 GHz CPU with 16 GB of RAM, using MATLAB R2014a on Windows 7 Ultimate.  Basically, I did the following:

- Test #1 - Set the random seed generator to 1 for reproducibility.  I wrote a loop that cycled 10000 times.  For each iteration in the loop, I generated a random integer 3000 x 3 matrix, then performed each of the methods that were described here.  I took note of how long it took for each method to complete after 10000 cycles.  The timing results are:

  1. David's method: `0.092129 seconds`
  2. rayryeng's method: `1.9828 seconds`
  3. natan's method: `0.20097 seconds`
  4. natan's `bsxfun` method: `0.10972 seconds`
  5. Divakar's `bsxfun` method: `0.0689 seconds`

As such, Divakar's method is the fastest, followed by David's `for` loop method, followed closely by natan's `bsxfun` method, followed by natan's original `kron` method, followed by the sloth (a.k.a mine).

- Test #2 - I decided to see how fast this would get as you increase the size of the matrix.  The set up was as follows.  I did 1000 iterations, and at each iteration, I increase the size of the matrix rows by 3000 each time.  As such, iteration 1 consisted of a 3000 x 3 matrix, the next iteration consisted of a 6000 x 3 matrix and so on.  The random seed was set to 1 again.  At each iteration, the time taken to complete the code was taken a note of.  To ensure fairness, the variables were cleared at each iteration before the processing code began.  As such, here is a `stem` plot that shows you the timing for each size of matrix.  I subsetted the plot so that it displays timings from 200000 x 3 to 300000 x 3.  Take note that the horizontal axis records the **number of rows** at each iteration.  The first stem is for 3000 rows, the next is for 6000 rows and so on.  The columns remain the same at 3 (of course).

[image]

I can't explain the random spikes throughout the graph.... probably attributed to something happening in RAM.  However, I'm very sure I'm clearing the variables at each iteration to ensure no bias.  In any case, Divakar and David are closely tied.  Next comes natan's `bsxfun` method, then natan's `kron` method, followed last by mine.  Interesting to see how Divakar's `bsxfun` method and David's `for` method are side-by-side in timing.

- Test #3 - I repeated what I did for Test #2, but using natan's suggestion, I decided to go on a logarithmic scale.  I did 6 iterations, starting at a 3000 x 3 matrix, and increasing the rows by 10 fold after.  As such, the second iteration had 30000 x 3, the third iteration had 300000 x 3 and so on, up until the last iteration, which is 3e8 x 3.

I have plotted on a semi-logarithmic scale on the horizontal axis, while the vertical axis is still a linear scale.  Again, the horizontal axis describes the number of rows in the matrix.

[image]

I changed the vertical limits so we can see most of the methods.  My method is so poor performing that it would squash the other timings towards the lower end of the graph.  As such, I changed the viewing limits to take my method out of the picture.  Essentially what was seen in Test #2 is verified here.

Comment: @rayreng Not surprised that your method is slower, I think the conversions to and from cells would be hurting it. If you use the profiler, where does the most time get spent? I'm surprised that my answer is faster than natan's though, JIT must be doing a good job here!

Comment: @David: I figured as much.  The conversion from matrices to cell and back is probably the killer.  Give me a few minutes and let me see where the profiler is locating where it's spending the most time.

Comment: @David: `cellfun` is where it's spending the most time.  It spends 64.6% of the time in this function, followed by `mat2cell` at 22.3%, then `cell2mat` at 6.3%.  Same conclusions with Test #2.  Most of the time is spent in `cellfun`, followed by `mat2cell`, then `cell2mat`.  Interesting!

Comment: @natan: You're very welcome :) I was curious myself!  We just need to add Luis Mendo's `bsxfun` implementation here to complete it.

Comment: So, Luis is probably in a suboptimal time zone (Madrid)... I couldn't help it so I also wrote a bsxfun solution... (see my edited answer)

Comment: @natan: No problem!  I tried the command in my Command Prompt and I got an inconsistent size error when subtracting.  No worries, I'll wait :)

Comment: @natan: No worries.  I see Divakar is now up so I'll be updating this post with his code as well.

Comment: Hmm... interesting.  I used `tic` and `toc` for timing.  Maybe I should redo this using `timeit`?

Comment: I dont know how timeit can be used other that anonmous functions... anyway, try testing different array sizes, for example a=(300,3) till a(3e6,e) and see if bsxfun and the for loop keeps on top...

Comment: @natan: You're very welcome.  I increased the number of iterations to 1000 for Test #2.  As such, the final size of matrix is 3e6 x 3.  I subsetted the plot so that it displays from 2e6 to 3e6.  I'll edit my post so you can see.

Comment: Thanks  rayryeng , however, I don't see why the range 2e6 to 3e6 is enough to understand the performance. I would scan a logarithmic spaced range (as done in my answer) that is 3e3,3e4,3e5,3e6...  this way you can see if different memory handling kick in etc. For matlab function I doubt there's any difference between 2e6 to 3e6 size arrays, this is not the case when going from 1e2 to 1e7 though...

Comment: @natan: That's a really good idea.  I should go on a logarithmic scale.  Bah. I'll do it now.  One moment.

Comment: @rayryeng I have just seen this very interesting Q&A, here in my "suboptimal time zone" :-) Would you mind including my answer in your tests?

Comment: @Divakar, rayryeng. That's true. For me it's OK if you just tell me how my code performs in a comment

Comment: @LuisMendo, rayryeng - Or a separate answer for community wiki could be made copying benchmarking stuff from this answer and adding Luis's results . Hope that's not too much of work. Purely a suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way to implement this with `bsxfun`, slightly different from [natan's bsxfun implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23880229/3293881) -

```
t1 = reshape(a,3,[]); %// a is the input matrix
out = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,t1,t1(1,:)),[],3); %// Desired output
```

Comment: that seems much better implementation +1 (at least in elegance). Let's see if it is faster...

Comment: @natan yeah I think so too! :) Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng Seems like `bsxfun` is the way to go! Thanks for compiling all those results!

Comment: @Divakar: Yup... `bsxfun` is king.  This is the function I know the least about so it's time to start reviewing it.  You're very welcome!

Comment: @Divakar: Updated my post to introduce more timings

Comment: Well done! Faster than previous `bsxfun` approach. +1

Answer (score 4):

Simple `for` loop. This does each 3x3 block separately.

```
A=randi(5,9,3)
B=A(1:3:end,:)
for i=1:length(A(:,1))/3
    D(3*i-2:3*i,:)=A(3*i-2:3*i,:)-repmat(B(i,:),3,1)
end
D
```

Whilst it may be possible to vectorise this, I don't think the performance gains would be worth it, unless you will do this many times. For a 3000x3 matrix it doesn't take long at all.

Edit: In fact this seems to be pretty fast. I think that's because Matlab's JIT compilation can speed up simple `for` loops well.

Comment: Check my edited post.  `for` loops are a winner here.  Nice going!

Comment: Did another timing test to include 2 `bsxfun` methods.  Check the edited post.

Comment: Did more using logarithmic scales.  Your method is still good!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using just indexing:

```
a(:) = a(:) - a(3*floor((0:numel(a)-1)/3)+1).';
```

Of course, the `3` above can be replaced by any other number. It works even if that number doesn't divide the number of rows.