# Vectorization of MATLAB/Octave loop

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

Can this for-loop be vectorized further?

```
for i = 1:length(formula)
ttable(i,abs(formula(i,:))) = -1*formula(i,:);
end
```

Where `formula` is a matrix and `ttable = NaN(length(formula),max(max(abs(formula))))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the code, what you are doing is that for each row of `ttable`, you wish to use the indices accessed by `abs(formula(i,:))` and set each of these locations to `-1*formula(i,:)`.

Noting @Divakar's clever spot, I am going to assume that each row has **unique absolute** values.  In other words, each row should not have instances where you could have `a` or `-a` in a row, where `a` is any number from `1` up to `size(formula,2)`.  The reason why is because in your computation of `abs(formula(i,:))`, `-a` and `a` will then map to the same column.  This will conflict and allow for overwriting into the same entry (Thanks @Divakar!)

What we can do is for each row of `formula`, convert these locations into column-major indices to access `ttable`.  After, assign the corresponding values of `-1*formula` into `ttable`.  In other words:

```
%// Find those columns that should be accessed
columnIndices = reshape(abs(formula).', 1, []);

%// For each column we are accessing, find the corresponding row
rowIndices = reshape(repmat(1:size(formula,2), size(formula, 1), 1), 1, []);

%// Find the column major indices we need to access overall
indices = sub2ind(size(formula), rowIndices, columnIndices);

%// Take those indices that we have computed above, and map them
%// to those columns we found earlier
ttable(indices) = -1*formula.';
```

Here is a small test I created.  This is also based on the same assumption of unique absolute values that I made before:

```
formula = [1 2 -3 4; 4 -2 3 1; 3 2 4 -1; -4 1 2 3];
ttable = NaN(length(formula),max(max(abs(formula))));

formula =

 1     2    -3     4
 4    -2     3     1
 3     2     4    -1
-4     1     2     3


ttable =

NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Using your approach, we get:

```
for i = 1:length(formula)
    ttable(i,abs(formula(i,:))) = -1*formula(i,:);
end

ttable =

-1    -2     3    -4
-1     2    -3    -4
 1    -2    -3    -4
-1    -2    -3     4
```

Using my approach, we get:

```
columnIndices = reshape(abs(formula).', 1, []);
rowIndices = reshape(repmat(1:size(formula,2), size(formula, 1), 1), 1, []);
indices = sub2ind(size(formula), rowIndices, columnIndices);
ttable(indices) = -1*formula.';

ttable =

-1    -2     3    -4
-1     2    -3    -4
 1    -2    -3    -4
-1    -2    -3     4
```

If your matrix is small, then the computational overhead by doing this instead of the `for` loop may be larger and so this will be inefficient.  However, if your matrix is larger, then this code may be faster.  Either way, I think your `for` loop approach is still good.  The JIT should kick in for `for` loops.  If you take a look at this post here when doing some timing tests for an algorithm where a `for` loop was used as one of the algorithms, the `for` loop was one of the algorithms that was the fastest.  Check here: [MATLAB: Subtracting matrix subsets by specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879888/matlab-subtracting-matrix-subsets-by-specific-rows/23880086#23880086)

Comment: My matrix is huge so that will definitely help. Thanks!

Comment: What if you have a positive and its negative counterpart in the same row, something like `-2` and `2`?

Comment: @Divakar - I considered that as well, but I didn't question the OP's objective.  I simply translated the code that he/she wrote above into something vectorized.  Good spot though.  I'm assuming that each row has **unique absolute** values.  Maybe this is something the OP has already enforced, but hasn't said so in the post.  You can also see that from my example, I ensured that the values were this way.

Comment: @rayryeng Hope its not too much of a trouble if that assumption is added to the solution to avoid any confusion?

Comment: @Divakar - Not at all.  I'll add that right now.  Thank you for your diligence.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which uses[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to generate the linear indices:

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (1:size(ttable,1)).' , (abs(formula)-1)*size(ttable,1));
ttable(ind) = -formula;
```