# Convert digit to vector octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

I have a vector `y = [0; 2; 4]`

I want to convert each element of it into vector, where all elements are zero but element with index equal to digit is 1.

I'd like to do it without loops.

For example `[0; 2; 4]` should be converted to

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

(in this example vector first index is 0)

Comment: Why without loops? It seems a random limitation.

Comment: how is the size of output matrix decided?

Comment: @Jongware - `for` loops are known to be notorious slow in MATLAB.  Doing it vectorized is always the suggested approach.  However, depending on what operation you are doing, `for` loops can be as fast as vectorized approaches due to the help of the JIT compiler as MATLAB essentially uses the JVM under the hood.  Check out this post if you're curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879888/matlab-subtracting-matrix-subsets-by-specific-rows/23880086#23880086

Answer (score 9):

The usual trick with [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) can be used to simplify the process. Let `n` denote the desired number of columns. Then

```
result = full(sparse(1:numel(y), y+1, 1, numel(y), n));
```

For example, `y = [0;2;4]` and `10` produce

```
result =
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1 from me too.  `sparse` is definitely the way to go, especially if the matrix size gets large.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to decide **how many** digits you want to represent each number.  In your case, you have 10 digits per number, so let's keep that in mind.

Once you do this, it's just a matter of indexing each element in your matrix.  In your case, you have 10 digits per number.  As such, do something like this:

```
y = [0; 2; 4]; %// Your digits array
out = zeros(numel(y), 10); %// 10 digits per number
ind = sub2ind(size(out), [1:numel(y)].', y+1);
out(ind) = 1;
```

The output should look like this:

```
out =

 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

Let's go through this code slowly.  `y` defines the digits you want per row of the output matrix.  `out` allocates a matrix of zeroes where the number of rows is defined by how many digits you want in `y`.  `out` will thus store your resulting matrix that you have shown us in your post.

The number of columns is 10, but you change this to be whatever you want.  `ind` uses a command called [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  This allows to completely vectorize the assignment of values in your `out` matrix and avoids a `for` loop.  The first parameter is an array of values that defines how many rows and columns are in your matrix that you are trying to assign things to.  In this case, it's just the size of `out`.  The second and third parameters are the rows and columns you want to access in your matrix.  In this case, the rows vary from 1 to as many elements as there are in `y`.  In our case, this is 3.  We want to generate one number per row, which is why it goes from 1 to 3.  The columns denote where we want to set the digit to one for each row.  As MATLAB indexes starting at 1, we have to make sure that we take `y` and **add by 1**.  `ind` thus creates the column-major indices in order to access our matrix.  The last statement finally accesses these locations and assigns a 1 to each location, thus producing our matrix.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 mainly for the detailed explanation