# Adding rows at equal interval in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 6954 by 222 matrix and I want to sum every 122 rows to get 57 by 222 matrix. If anybody have the solution please help me.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but look here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879888/matlab-subtracting-matrix-subsets-by-specific-rows - Here they were subtracting and it was done by every three rows.  Modify the code so that you're adding and that you are summing over 122 rows.

Comment: Also, try to always include what have you tried in your questions. If you have a chance take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and of-course [`sum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)

```
rowstosum = 122;
out = permute(sum(permute(reshape(A.',size(A,2),rowstosum,[]),[2 1 3])),[3 2 1])
```

**Sample check** (for 10x3 matrix with 2 `rowstosum`)

```
>> A

A =

 8     8     2
 2     9     5
 9     8     2
10     4     1
 6     6     9
 9     1     6
 6     2    10
 2     2     7
 2     7     6
 5     5     9

>> out

out =

10    17     7
19    12     3
15     7    15
 8     4    17
 7    12    15
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be an efficient approach as it uses lightweight [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) & [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) alongwith the compulsory `sum` -

```
cutlen = 122 %// Cut after this many number of rows, for summing purposes
out = squeeze(sum(reshape(A,cutlen,[],size(A,2)),1));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty efficient as well:

```
A = ... %// input array

iL = 122;   %// interval length
y = filter(ones(1,iL),1,A);
y = y(iL:iL:end,:);
```

Unlike [**`conv`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)/[**`conv2`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) the [**`filter`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function allows also 1-D convolution of 2D-Data. But again [Divakar's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30289414/2605073) seems to be the fastest.

This approach seems pretty close though:

```
out = reshape(sum(reshape(A,iL,[])),[],size(A,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function can be used to do the accumulation of rows.

Let `A` denote the matrix, `n` the number of rows to be summed, and `B` the result. Then

```
r = repmat(ceil(1/n:1/n:size(A,1)/n).',1,size(A,2)); %'
c = repmat(1:size(A,2),size(A,1),1);
B = full(sparse(r,c,A));
```